# Integrating FirebaseCommunity pod with macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, firebase, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate Firebase into my OSX app with such pod

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyAppTarget' do
   pod 'FirebaseCommunity', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git'
end
```

But I get totally nothing: "No such module 'Firebase'" when

```
import Firebase
```

I've already tried all sorts of cleaning, different Podfile variants, even all combinations swift/objc osx/ios, but got nothing. Other pods work.

What can I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirebaseCommunity is NOT (yet) Firebase.

FirebaseCommunity does contain the source for a subset of Firebase components but it does not yet integrate with the rest of Firebase via CocoaPods.

To use the Firebase subset available in the FirebaseCommunity CocoaPod and/or you're targeting OS/X, thoroughly read the [README](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/README.md) and access in source via:

```
import FirebaseCommunity
```

Also, you'll also need to specify at least one subspec in the Podfile like:

```
pod 'FirebaseCommunity/Database'
```

BTW, we plan to consolidate Firebase and FirebaseCommunity when CocoaPods 1.4 releases with its support for [static library framework CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6811).

Comment: Great thanks! It began to work adding /Core components in Podfile like this pod 'FirebaseCommunity/Core', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git'
But it look unobvious, doesn't it? Maybe it worths adding in README.md?

Comment: @user1261347 Good idea! The docs are now updated. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/174

Answer (score 0):

Try changing target 'MyAppTarget' to your actual project name. Make sure you have installed the Firebase pod correctly first.